# Can't add remote servers to Mysql Fabric group

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-web-services

I was trying to add one AWS ubuntu server to my mysql fabric group, but I encountered this error: `ServerError: Error accessing server (aws-db01:3306): 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'aws-db01:3306' (111 Connection refused).`

I've allowed all traffic coming into my AWS server, but I can't telnet its 3306 port from my local server. What might be the problem? Should I grant remote access rights to mysql fabric server user?

Comment: Are you certain that mysql service is started on aws-db01?

Comment: Yes, mysql is running on aws-db01